# Plotting Points Using Matplotlib Showing Incorrectly

Tags: python, numpy

My goal is to create two random arrays of data and check to see if they fall inside a circle of radius one, using the formula x^2 + y^2 < 1. Those that fall inside the circle should be plotted as a blue circle and those that fall outside the circle should be plotted as a yellow circle.

I have managed to create the arrays, check if they are inside the circle and then plot them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


plots = 100
#creates x-coordinates
dataOne = np.random.random(size = plots)
#creates y-coordinates
dataTwo = np.random.random(size = plots)

circle = plt.Circle((0,0), 1, alpha = 0.1)
plt.gca().add_patch(circle)
plt.xlim(0, 2)
plt.ylim(0, 2)


squareDataOne = dataOne ** 2
squareDataTwo = dataTwo ** 2

squareRootData = np.sqrt(squareDataOne + squareDataTwo)

insideCircle = squareRootData < 1

for values in insideCircle:
    if values == True:
       plt.plot(squareDataOne, squareDataTwo, 'bo')
    else:
        plt.plot(squareDataOne, squareDataTwo, 'yo')

plt.show()
```

My problem lies in the plot itself. When plotted I have points falling outside the circle that are still coloured blue. No yellow circles are appearing on the plot at all. Any suggestions on where my code is wrong is appreciated.

Comment: You are not looping trough `squareDataOne`, you are plotting them all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try

```
for i in range(len(insideCircle)):
    if insideCircle[i]:
        plt.plot(dataOne[i], dataTwo[i], 'bo')
    else:
        plt.plot(dataOne[i], dataTwo[i], 'yo')

plt.show()
```

EDIT : you should plot `dataOne` and `dataTwo` instead of `squareDataOne` and `squareDataTwo` (changed in the code)

Answer (score 0):

You need to think more in vectorized terms and learn a bit more about slicing numpy arrays.  There is a very elegant solution to this:

```py
is_inside = np.sqrt(dataOne**2 + dataTwo**2) < 1
plt.plot(dataOne[is_inside], dataTwo[is_inside], 'bo')
plt.plot(dataOne[~is_inside], dataTwo[~is_inside], 'yo')
```